# How to change 2 strings using a function, by changing their pointers' value

Tags: c, function, pointers, swap

```
main()

char *s1="Second";
char *s2="First";
swap(s1,s2);
printf("%s\n",s1);
printf("%s\n",s2);
```

I have as an exercise, to swap those 2 strings above **(so that the one that executes the program will see "First Second" instead of "Second First")**, by changing the values of their pointers, using the function swap (that I have to make).

Answer (score 3):

This would do what you need

```
void swap(char **s1, char **s2){
  char *temp=*s1;
  *s1=*s2;
 *s2=temp;
}

int main(){
  char *s1="second";
  char *s2="first";
  swap(&s1,&s2);
  printf("%s",s1);
  printf("%s",s2);
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is the best answer that is actually in C.  It doesn't use tricks, and it doesn't use c++-only functionality.

Comment: Wow! This code may be genious for C lovers, but you changed the user's code: `swap(&s1,&s2);` is not `swap(s1,s2);`. IMHO, this is more serious than ignoring the tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *a="vinod";
char *b="kumar";

a=(char*)((int)a+(int)b);
b=(char*)((int)a-(int)b);
a=(char*)((int)a-(int)b);
printf("%s%s",a,b);
```

Comment: Uhh.. aren't there serious buffer overflow issues here?  I think you're really thinking about the XOR trick, but from what I've learned recently, that's actually an undefined behavior for non-integer (including pointer) types.  While this may work sometimes, I'd recommend staying away from this solution.  It's "tricky", likely not correct, and the compiler will do a good job for you if you do things the common way.  Do what Liviu says and use a temporary pointer.

Answer (score -1):

```
inline void swap(char*& s1, char*& s2)
{
    char* temp = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm kind of new here, but I don't think it's alright to solve your school problems :p

Comment: This isn't valid C.  This is C++.  Either you mis-tagged your question, or this isn't a valid solution.

Comment: @xaxxon The tag is incorrect, you can't do `swap(s1,s2);` in C, see the next solution.

Comment: i'm guessing the question is tagged correctly but the asker doesn't know he can't do what he wants and needs to change the prototype for swap, not change languages.

Comment: @xaxxon Or maybe the teacher written the above code (the question) and demanded the implementation. I'm in a middle of a minor polemic right now: it seems it is common these days to learn directly C++ (and skip C entirely)

Comment: @`Nor Tee` Could you please accept an answer ? Or clarify the problem: do you want C or C++ or C/C++ ? Thanks are alright until they start to vote me down :P.